# Where can I find aircraft design data?

Tags: aircraft-design, aircraft-performance

I am looking for a library of different aircraft data, variables such as coefficient of lift, drag, etc.

I've gotten access to the POH/AFMS and the FAA TCDS' but they often modify the core data for operations and its not the true numbers, so to speak. I remember at university some textbooks had tables of the data but those can be difficult and expensive to access.

I would completely understand if this data is next to impossible to find as I can see manufactures would hold such info close to their chest.

I am specifically hunting for data on the C208 and C208B.

Comment: I get that the price of text books is obscene (it was when I was in college decades ago), but buying some used texts at the local college/university (particularly if they have an aviation program) or at an online book retailer (hmmm... where would one find one of those...) might be a reasonably inexpensive way of gathering this data if you really need it.

Comment: Resource location questions are not considered on-topic on this forum.

Answer (score 1):

I once spent substantial effort digitizing the POH data for a C208 and working to fit a drag polar to the data.  This depends on your propeller model.

This kind of data is not generally published by the manufacturer.  The best you'll typically find is someone else's estimate.

Here is what I ended up with.

```
Sref = 279;   % ft^2
W = 8750;     % lbf
AR = 9.35;
oswalde = 0.86;
K = 1.0/(pi*oswalde*AR);

CD0 = 0.0348;
deltaCDpod = 0.0046;

polar = @(CL) CD0 + K*CL.^2.0;
polarpod = @(CL) CD0 + deltaCDpod + K*CL.^2.0;
```

I have used a slightly sanitized/rounded version of the above in numerous AIAA papers including [AIAA 2015-1676](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/282414820_Modeling_of_Electric_Motor_Driven_Propellers_for_Conceptual_Aircraft_Design).  This paper does not include details of how the polar was obtained, but it does provide a resource you can cite.

Answer (score 0):

Some wings use [NACA coded airfoils](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NACA_airfoil) and indeed the 208 uses a [blend of two wing root: NACA 23017.424, wing tip: NACA 23012](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cessna_208_Caravan). You can [find info (and generate them) here](http://airfoiltools.com/airfoil/naca5digit?MNaca5DigitForm%5Bcl%5D=0.3&MNaca5DigitForm%5BposKey%5D=15_0&MNaca5DigitForm%5Bthick%5D=17&MNaca5DigitForm%5BnumPoints%5D=81&MNaca5DigitForm%5BcosSpace%5D=0&MNaca5DigitForm%5BcosSpace%5D=1&MNaca5DigitForm%5BcloseTe%5D=0&yt0=Plot). There is lift and drag info for the [tip airfoil (23012)](http://airfoiltools.com/airfoil/details?airfoil=naca23012-il) listed there but they dont seem to have the root foil listed at that particular side.

[You can find NASA's test data for the 23012 airfoil here](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19930091603/downloads/19930091603.pdf) and some even [older test data on it here](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19930092816/downloads/19930092816.pdf).

Comment: That is what I am currently working with via XFLR5, but I am seeking the "official" or fully tested numbers.

Comment: @JeffreyMG see my edits